# Using Inner joins in Entity Framework on multiple tables?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `student` table in my database with columns `Id, Name, DepartmentId, CollegeId, CityId` etc and a `Department` table, `College` table to map to the `DepartmentId`, `CollegeId` in the `Student` table.

Now I want to pass `CityId` and retrieve `Id, Name, DepartmentName, CollegeName` with help of the corresponding tables using inner join based on the `CityId`.

I'm implementing a method `FindAll()` which takes in `CityId` as the input parameter and retrieves data based on `CityId`

```
  public IEnumerable<StudentRegionEntity> FindAll(int CityId)
  {
     var totalStudents = new List<StudentRegionEntity>();

     foreach(var entity in this.Dbcontext.Students)
     {
     }
  }
```

In the foreach loop I want to bind the list of students with `Id, Name, Department, College` fields, how can I use joins and implement the functionality for `FindAll()`?

Comment: thank you, will not repeat in the future.

Comment: Using Joins leads you to adding extaneous, confusing Entity classes (what else do you use StudentRegionEntity for?). Just use the Navigation properties: `Student.Region.Name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var studentEntities =  this.Dbcontext.Students
    .Include("StudentList").Where(s => s.cityId == CityId).ToList()
```

this will give the list of all the StudentEntity entities with StudentRegionEntity attached, using one join query to the database.

Comment: im not able to understand , how should i use 1 join and i have multiple tables and you used "studentlist" as string

Comment: It is a path to a property in your StudentEntity class. Property name StudentList. It will filter SutdentEntities based on city id and at the same time join StudentRegionEntity and retrieve StudentRegionEntity for each studentEntity that you get back

Comment: ok i got the values to StudentEntitites ,how can i get the values from studentEntities and bind to my list totalStudents?

Comment: What do you mean totalStudents? you need total count? Can you post your code again in the question?